Cucumber java Pico Container create component through method return
I have a bunch of step definition classes that I would like to inject a shared client in.
class FirstStepDefinition {
  private final Client client;

  public FirstStepDefinition(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
  }
}

I don't own Client class and it does not have a default constructor. So how do I store construct the Client instance with an argument inside pico container to be injected elsewhere?
public Client client() {
  return Client("api-key");
}


You can extend Client class (unless it is final one) that would have default constructor calling super("api-key").
Due to polymorphism you will be able to use this class wherever original Client is required.
